# Knotes - Show All Notes/Alt+Shift+S - Sometimes It Does Not Work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, user-interface

Sometimes I use the shortcut (Alt+Shift+S) in KDE to maximize/show all notes in KNotes it does not work and the notes appearing all grouped on the taskbar.

Any solution/workaround for this problem?

Comment: I suspect this should have been submitted as a bug to kde, but since it's years old now, and the behaviour doesn't seem to occur for me, maybe it's already fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I present a simple workaround:

- Install "xdotool":

"apt-get install xdotool"

- Create the file "/home/<user_name>/<your_path>/KNotesWorkaround.sh" with the following content:

  ```
   #!/bin/ksh
  killall knotes
  knotes
  sleep 0.5
  xdotool keydown alt shift Z; xdotool keyup alt shift Z
  ```
- Give execute permission to the file:

  ```
  chmod a+x '/home/<user_name>/<your_path>/KNotesWorkaround.sh'
  ```
- Open the KDE's "System Stettings" and follow "Shortcuts and Gestures" -> "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" and in "KDE component" select "KNotes". In "Show All Notes" modify to "Alt+Shift+Z".
- In "Custom Shortcuts" select in "name" with the mouse's second button "New" -> "Global Shortcut" -> "Command/URL" and create a shortcut with the following name "Workaround KNotes (Show All Notes)". In the "Trigger" tab put "Alt+Shift+S" and in the "Action" tab put "/home/<user_name>/<your_path>/KNotesWorkaround.sh".

This scheme closes, opens KNotes and passes through the "xdotool" application the keystrokes "Alt+Shift+Z" so it shows all your notes every time.

That's it!